# https request to another domain with redirect using php

Tags: php, redirect, curl, https, cross-domain

I have auto-login link on one domain - this domain is used for authorization:

`https://example.com/api/login/{key}/{username}`

After following this link, user is redirected into control panel:

`https://example.com`

If something is wrong - user redirected to

`https://example.com/login page.`

In another domain `example2.com` users have billing panel and link `https://example.com/api/login/{key}/{username}` is placed in it.

So i need to do check from `example2.com` to `example.com` like this:

```
$url = https://example.com/api/login/{key}/{username};
if function-to-check-autologin($url) == "true" {
  //do something
}
```

My searching result is curl, but i cant configurate request by myself.

How could I do it? curl or another way?

Comment: Which domains are different? How do auto-login work? It will be difficult to do it in a secure manner, basically you have to use username and password to access the second site.

Comment: example.url - this domain doing auto-login. check request from another domain

Comment: @raskalbass So you want to do POST request with your credentials and learn what URL it redirected to by the server. Did I understand you correct?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained what 'auto-login' is, or how it works. All your domains are 'example.com' so they're all the same domain. Surely you don't make it easy for people to understand your question. I will try to state how I understand it.

> You've got a user logged in on one internet domain and you want to redirect
>   them to a second domain where they should remain logged in.

There are many ways you can do this, but they all depend on certain conditions.

1. If you use the standard http login method you could redirect to second domain with:

   https://username:password@example.com

Since you indicate you're using a SSL certificate on both sites that would be reasonable safe. This will work even if you don't share a database.

2. If both domains are using the same database, you could handover an encrypted link to the logged in session of the user. This is how I do it normally. I keep sessions in my database, and each session has an ID. I encrypt that, any good method will do, and send it over to the second domain where I decrypt it like this:

   https://example.com?key=DgGyC28Sw3eQFvY9hz2dBkfmCa5zMgV6nN4Jj8VeD76chf7

Of course the session itself should tell you whether the user is logged in. Make sure your encryption method is safe.

In both cases, if the URL gets into the wrong hands, a login could be faked. That's why the use of SSL is important, but some risks remain.

Comment: Sorry, but you not understand question, so i edit it a little bit

Comment: Ah, you want to do it the other way around. Check from the second domain wether the user is logged in on the first. That's quite simple: Make a page on the first domain that returns 'correct' when logged in and 'wrong' when not logged in and react to that response on the second domain.

Comment: thanks it may be the answer, but what about variant without making edition on example.com ?

Comment: What do you mean by: 'without making edition on example.com'?

Comment: i mean - doing check that i discribe in question just with request from domain example2.com, without making page or function on the first domain example.com

Comment: Well, no, except when you have some other means, for instance via the database, to get information to the example2.com. See my answer about sessions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72114/discussion-between-raskalbass-and-kiko-software).

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is vague, I would give you some clues.

First of all, you have to set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` option to `false` unless you're going to deal with peer's certificate.

Also you have to tell CURL to handle redirects. This assume that you set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option as well as `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` and `CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER`.

In order to send POST data with request you have to set `CURLOPT_POST` option to `true` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to array of POST data or url-encoded string.

Once CURL request is done you can learn all information about it by [`curl_getinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) function. Calling it with `CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT` as 2nd parameter will give number of redirects, and `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` - last effective URL.

So the code might look like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 1,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_array,
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT) == 1 && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL) == $sample_redirect_url)
    echo 'OK';
```