# php curl post redirect

Tags: php, redirect, curl

Im trying to integrate a bank api for redirect payment.
Im using curl post method but i want to be able to follow the redirect after the post.
Here is my code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://paycenter.piraeusbank.gr/redirection/pay.aspx');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'data' => $data
));
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

After the post it supposed that i have to be redirected in a url like

```
https://paycenter.piraeusbank.gr/redirection/4234sgsfdgfsg/pay.aspx
```

Instead of that im redirecting to:

```
http://mytestdomain.org/redirection/4234sgsfdgfsg/pay.aspx
```

which obviously ends up in 404 error

Comment: Do you have any redirect code??? or its redirect automatically?

Comment: If i make a simple post from an html form it redirects me to the banks page

Comment: So you don't have redirection code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manipulate your response and then write hard code to redirect this script to particular page as curl execute that url on your server.

Comment: can you give an example? as i understand first i want to block the redirection and then grab the headers from curl with the redirect url and after redirect the user

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
```

This will automatically set the Referer, example: redirection.

**EDIT**:Check out this answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810040/https-request-to-another-domain-with-redirect-using-php#answer-28812639), Maybe it will help you out a little.

Comment: I get the same result with CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE,ive tried to also add CURLOPT_REFERER, https://paycenter.piraeusbank.gr/ but with the same result